# Boiling peeled peanuts

Tags: boiling, nuts, peanuts

Recently I became interested in making some boiled peanuts for myself, as I have gathered that it is a very cheap, tasty (I like peanuts) and healthy food. However, every recipe that I find involves peanuts in shells. And in my local stores I can only find the raw peanuts without the shell , I will have to spend more effort to get the plain uncooked peanuts with shell.

So, the question is - what is the recipe for boiling peanuts without the shell? (if this is even meaningful to cook them this way).

**UPDATE** Sorry english is not my native language, so I reworded the question to be clearer.

Comment: There's a Good Eats episode on boiled peanuts.

Comment: @Jay : yes, [there is](http://www.goodeatsfanpage.com/Season11/EA1112.htm), but he calls for [unshelled peanuts](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/boiled-peanuts-recipe.html).

Comment: 'shelled' often means 'the shell has been removed'. not 'it has a shell'.

Comment: Ah, that rewording makes things a lot clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to admit that I have never heard of boiling shelled peanuts, but apparently it's not uncommon.  From [ZimboKitchen.com](http://www.zimbokitchen.com/boiled-shelled-peanuts-nzungu-dzakabikwa/) :

> Quick Instructions
>
> - Get your main ingredient ready – 400 g shelled peanuts. Run them quickly through some water to remove dust and other particles.
> - Put your peanuts in a medium size pot and add your first 1 ltr of water. Add 1 tsp salt and partially cover your pot and bring to the boil. Add another 1 ltr of water when your initial water is finished.
> - After an average of 1 1/2 hrs (90min) your peanuts should be boiled and tender to enjoy. If not continue boiling until desired tenderness is achieved.
>
> You may serve your snack and go work or play!

Notes:

- You do need *raw* peanuts.
- Other sites use pretty much the same recipe (salt & water), but called for longer cooking time. Some said several hours. I would suggest tasting as you go along and adjust salt and cooking time to your liking.